# How to use *args to combine multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, args, sublist

I currently have this function, which I'd like to make scalable to take in more lists. In other words, I'd like to use this function whether I have to combine 2 lists or 10 lists.

```
l1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']] 
l2 = [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F']]

[L1 + L2 for L1, L2 in zip(l1, l2)]
```

result should be:

```
[['a','b','c','A','B','C'],['d','e','f','D','E','F']]
```

Comment: Are `L1` through to `L4` sample outputs or sample inputs? They don't work as inputs

Comment: They are sample inputs and they work for me. After I define l1 and l2, I use [L1 + L2 for L1,L2 in zip(l1,l2)]

Comment: You are using confusing names here; lowercase `l` for inputs, uppercase `L` for loop variables. Are your `l1` and `l2` names for the input the same as the `L1` and `L2` lists in your post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
[sum(l, []) for l in zip(*lists)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> l1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
>>> l2 = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
>>> lists = (l1, l2)
>>> [sum(l, []) for l in zip(*lists)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'A', 'B', 'C'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'D', 'E', 'F']]
```

or, as a function:

```
def combine_lists(*lists):
    return [sum(l, []) for l in zip(*lists)]

combine_lists(l1, l2)
```

Comment: brilliant! just to confirm the function would look like this:  def CombineLists(self,*lists):
  [sum(*l, []) for l in zip(*lists)]

Comment: @Chris: you'd need a `return` in there.

Comment: Miscommunication on my part. I want to zip up the lists not just simply combine them. For example, l1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']] and l2 = [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F']]. result should be: [['a','b','c','A','B','C'],['d','e','f','D','E','F']]

Comment: @Chris: now that's a sample I can work with. :-) Updated to demonstrate that that is exactly what the code does.

Comment: I'm just not getting that. I get: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]

Comment: @Chris: How are you building `lists` and how are you passing that to `zip()`? The sample in my answer is an actual Python session, so the code works.

Comment: I use this function:  def CombineLists(self,*lists):
  return [sum(l, []) for l in zip(*lists)]   and call it with this    l1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']] 
  l2 = [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F']]
  lists = (l1,l2)
  return CombineLists(lists)

Comment: @Chris: You make one list too many. Use `CombineLists(l1, l2)`.